# Permutation of a 4 character string made up of letters and numbers

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

This is a straightforward question but I didn't pay attention in school. I want to know how many permutations there are for a 4 charcter string made up of numbers and letters.

After a quick look around my guess is as follows:

```
Letters: 26
Numbers: 10
Total = 36^4 = 1679616
```

Is the above correct? How would the answer differ if I asked for the combination instead of the permutation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your answer of $36^4$ is correct assuming that repetition is allowed. If repetition is not allowed, the answer would have been : $^{36}P_4 = 36*35*34*33$

Now if you just want combination, then the answer would be : $^{36}C_4 = \frac{36*35*34*33}{1*2*3*4}$

If you are new to Permutations and Combinations, you can refer these links to know more about [Permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) and [Combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).